# How to loop through each cell in excel to check cell contains date and then converting date to string

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am new to python and currently working on SAP scripting,
I want to loop through each cell in excel to check cell contains date and then converting date to string and then saving entire excel file to text using python.

```
import openpyxl
from datetime import date
wb=openpyxl.load_workbook("C:\\Users\\Nema\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\export.xlsx")
ds = datetime()
for cell in wb:
if cell.value = ds
print('Done')
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Hi, what do you mean by "saving entire excel file to text using python"? Do you need to produce a .txt file or the excel cells must be converted from "date" to "general text" cell type? In the first case you should provide the expected format format (tabular or comma separated file, fixed lenght fields etc)

Answer (score 1):

This should loop through all the excel cells in the area where values exist, find all "date" cells, and update the input excel by converting them into string format

It is not clear from your question wheather the result required is a txt or an excel file, but it will not change a lot

```
import openpyxl
import datetime

file_name = 'export.xlsx'
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(file_name)

# using ds will check against timestamp
# using today will check only the date (not time)
ds = datetime.datetime.now()
today = datetime.date.today()

for worksheet in wb:  # loop through worksheets

    # loop through rows (only rows with content are considered)
    for row in worksheet.iter_rows():

        # loop through row cells
        for cell in row:

            # check if is date and if required value date
            if cell.is_date and cell.value.date() == today:

                # convert into string
                # here you can convert the date in the format needed
                cell.value = str(today)
                print('Done')

# update the input excel
wb.save(file_name)
```

Example of input excel:

[image: Example of input excel]

The result is the cell A1 converted in string format (it's just an example, you can format it in any way). The stiles (fonts, colors) still remain

[image: Result]